# "Error MSB3073" in Visual Studio 2010 - post-build command dosen't handle line breaks?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, post-build-event

I have a post build command in Visual Studio 2010:

```
setlocal
cd D:\1.5\BINZ
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
D:
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin\cpack.exe" -C $(Configuration) --config ./CPackConfig.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
```

On one PC this works, on another doesn't: I get error MSB3037 for every line.

```
3>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal

3>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: cd D:\1.5\BINZ
```

etc.

One strange thing is that when I open project properties and look into Post-build event command that I stated above - the line breaks I see as squares.

Could it be a problem with line breaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a totally different problem (path length longer than 256), it had nothing to do with post-build event syntax - so this question should be removed altogether.